# How to verify the returned JSON response is in sorting order?

Tags: javascript, groovy, jmeter, beanshell

I have an API to fetch the list of employee Name's in an organization and it supports order by clause.
I invoked an API "get /employeeName?$ordeyby=name desc". I got the results like below,

```
{
"value":[
{
  "name":"Sam"
},
{
  "name":"Peter"
},
{
  "name":"Harry"
},
{
  "name":"Arnold"
}]
}
```

I have parsed each name and stored into a variable of string type.

How can I verify using JAVA Script/BeanShell/Groovy, that the returned response is in descending order?

Can anyone please help here. Any of the above-mentioned languages is fine and I want this needs to be implemented in JMeter.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) as a child of the request which returns the above JSON
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def expected = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..name').sort().reverse()

   new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).value.eachWithIndex { def entry, int i ->
       if (!entry.name.equals(expected.get(i))) {
           AssertionResult.setFailure(true)
           AssertionResult.setFailureMessage('Order mismatch, expected: ' + expected.get(i) + ', got: ' + entry.name)
       }
   }
   ```
3. That's it, in case of expected alphabetical descending order the sampler will be successful, otherwise you will get an error message indicating which name is expected and what is the actual one

More information:

- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Groovy Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: This solution helped me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort it in js using this approach

```
var employers = [
    {
      "name":"Sam"
    },
    {
      "name":"Peter"
    },
    {
      "name":"Harry"
    },
    {
      "name":"Arnold"
    }];

    console.log(employers.sort(function(e1,e2){
    var alc = e1.name.toLowerCase(), blc = e2.name.toLowerCase();
      return alc > blc ? 1 : alc < blc ? -1 : 0;
    }));
```

Comment: I'd hate to inherit that code.  Nested ternaries are a bear to read and your variable names are not very descriptive...

Comment: makes sense, I provided example for you. If you hate ternaries you can use this `return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());`

Comment: API returns the response in a sorted manner, I just want to verify the sorting of return response.

Comment: @Hari Then I suppose you could sort the response, and then compare it to the original response?

Comment: @Hari That's what we want.. for you to post the code you tried, and why you say it "didn't work".